# Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A \subset X$ compact. Show that $A$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A \subset X$ compact. Show that $A$ is closed.

Pick $x \in X \setminus A$, then since $X$ is Hausdorff there exists disjoint $O_x$ and $O_A$. Since $O_x \subset X \setminus A \implies X \setminus A$ is open. Thus $A$ is closed.

I'm not following how can they make the assumption that $O_x \subset X \setminus A$? Even though $x \in X \setminus A$ I don't think that implies that the neighbourhood of $X$ must be in $X \setminus A$?

Comment: This is just part of the proof, right?

Comment: "then since X is Hausdorff there exists disjoint $O_x$ and $O_A$" such that what?

Comment: It's the whole proof from a book I'm reading. They're relying on a theorem proved earlier that states that in a Hausdorff space we can seperate the neighborhood and $A$.

Comment: @Lakri tsa Hausdorff  space means any two points are "strongly" separated by two open sets. You can't separate a point from a set. But since $T_2\subset T_3$ , you can separate a point from a closed set not containing that point. And you can't assume $A$ is closed upfront.

Comment: I think you can seperate a _singleton_ $\{x\}$ from a set @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lakri tsa Hausdorff  space means any two points are "strongly" separated by two open sets. You can't separate a point from a set. But since $T_2\subset T_3$ , you can separate a point from a closed set not containing that point. And you can't assume $A$ is closed upfront.

$A\subset X$ compact and $X$ Hausdorff implies $A\subset X$ is closed.

Hint: $x\in X\setminus A$ .

Then, for any point $a\in A $ $\exists U_{x_a}, U_a $ such that $U_{x_a} \cap U_a=\emptyset$

$\{U_a:a\in A\}$ is a open cover of $A$.

Suppose, $\{U_{a_i}:i\in I \}$ is a finite subcover.

Choose, $U=\cap_{i\in I}U_{x_{a_i}}$

Then, $U \subset X\setminus A$

Comment: How do you get the conclusion $U \subset X\setminus A$ from letting $U=\cap_{i\in I}U_{x_{a_i}}$?

Comment: $A\subset \cup_{i\in I } U_{a_i}$ and  $U_{x_{a_i}}\cap U_{a_i}=\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$